# How to use a pipe in a foreach statement

Tags: bash

I have a for loop I'd like to run in bash like:

```
for i in user_* do; cat $i | ./fetch_contact.php ; done;
```

Always gives an error like

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

I assume it has something to do with the pipe, but nothing I try to add in (parenthesis, etc) wrap the pipe sufficiently. How do you use a pipe in a command like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bash, [do is a command](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html). Also, it is `for` not `foreach`. Here's the fix:

```
for i in user_*; do cat $i | ./fetch_contact.php; done;
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out getting the semicolons and everything else right makes this whole pipe thing moot.

```
for i in user_*; do cat $i | ./fetch_contact.php; done;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why loop?

```
cat user_* | ./fetch_contact.php
```

Comment: Because this concatenates all the files before feeding them to the script, which may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: If the OP runs it like what he posted in his questions, than catting everything to php script is equivalent to using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach i in user_*; do cat $i | ./fetch_contact.php ; done;`

Semicolon should go before `do`, not after.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `cat`:

```
for i in user_* ; do ./fetch_contact.php < "$i" ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

here's one with some checking

```
for file in user_*
do
  if [ -f "$file" ];then
    ./fetch_contact.php < "$file"
  fi
done
```